# ID процесса в C++

Tags: c++

Вопрос из разряда просто любопытных: почему в С++ не добавят функцию аналогичную:

```
std::this_thread::get_id()
```

Только для получения ID процесса. ?

Ну и тогда уж и функцию создания процесса, по аналогии с созданием потока.

Comment: Ответ всегда одинаковый: потому что никто не выдвинул такое предложение, или оно не было принято.

Comment: ибо есть getpid https://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=getpid&category=2&russian=0

Comment: @Oh-Ben-Ben, это ни как не может быть "ибо" - так как этой функции нет ни в Си, не в С++.

Comment: Видимо это слишком ОС-специфично, очень много проблем с единообразным интерфейсом (классом) для всех случаев

Comment: @Staxcelrom я боюсь вы не понимаете что язык, интерфейс ядра и стандартная библиотека разные вещи,  Не хочу расстраивать, но иначе нет у вас вариантов  - вот вам буст в пример https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/boost/interprocess/detail/os_thread_functions.hpp - ах да это же не с/с++  в нем нет процессов

Comment: @Oh-Ben-Ben, вы сами то поняли что написали ?